# Aligning flex items vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I am making cards using flexbox(https://jsfiddle.net/vs37qo0r/):

```css
/* Only included flex related styles*/

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*default*/
  align-items: stretch;
  /*default*/
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>Feature 1</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum dignissim turpis. Ut lacus leo, sagittis at ullamcorper eu, auctor a arcu. Sed non mi sed turpis rhoncus faucibus eu viverra.
    </p>
    <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
  </div>
  <!-- two more cards of same format-->
</div>
```

Each `<h3>` and `<p>` line up with each other. But, not every `<p>` is the same size, which then throws off where the `<button>` is layed out. How can I tell all of the `<button>`s to line up with each other regardless of the size of the `<p>` above it?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind would be to set a fixed height to every `p` but I guess it's not very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

- Set `.card` to `display: flex`
- Enclose `h3, p` in a wrapper with `flex: 1`
- Set the button to be at `flex-end`

[jfFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x1fd2k0/)

```css
 body{
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row; /*default*/
    align-items: stretch; /*default*/
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .card{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .card__content {
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .button {
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
 <div class="card__content">
 
  <h3>Feature 1</h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum dignissim turpis. Ut lacus leo, sagittis at ullamcorper eu, auctor a arcu. Sed non mi sed turpis rhoncus faucibus eu viverra.
  </p>
  
 </div>
  <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
</div>
<div class="card">
<div class="card__content">
  <h3>Feature 2</h3>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum
  </p>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
</div>
<div class="card">
<div class="card__content">
  <h3>Feature 3</h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum dignissim turpis. Ut lacus leo, sagittis at ullamcorper eu, auctor a arcu. Sed non mi sed turpis rhoncus faucibus eu viverra.
  </p>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/ouwvpbh9/)

There is no need for a wrapper or more than 3 additional properties.  Set `.card` to flex:

```
.card {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  ....
}
```

Set `.card p` to `flex: 1`

```
.card p {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Does `flex: 1;`tell all `p` elements to take up the same amount of space?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, well, `flex` is shorthand for `flex-grow: 1` when it has just one number ilke that.  `flex-grow` is a little complicated: it sets a ratio, and sets how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to that item.  You can [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `.card` elements flex-parents themselves, then play with the [`justify-content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

```
.card{
    …
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*default*/
  align-items: stretch;
  /*default*/
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Feature 1</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum dignissim turpis. Ut lacus leo, sagittis at ullamcorper eu, auctor a arcu. Sed non mi sed turpis rhoncus faucibus eu viverra.
      </p>
      <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Feature 2</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum
      </p>
      <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Feature 3</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum dignissim turpis. Ut lacus leo, sagittis at ullamcorper eu, auctor a arcu. Sed non mi sed turpis rhoncus faucibus eu viverra.
      </p>
      <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with you jsfiddle version:

there I added these extra code, and you never have to touch your HTML for it!

```
.card{
 ...
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  margin-top: auto !important;
}
```

and it's working fine!

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* default */
  align-items: stretch;
  /* default */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Feature 1</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum dignissim turpis. Ut lacus leo, sagittis at ullamcorper eu, auctor a arcu. Sed non mi sed turpis rhoncus faucibus eu viverra.
      </p>
      <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Feature 2</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum
      </p>
      <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h3>Feature 3</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam finibus arcu est, id mollis ex tincidunt blandit. Morbi dictum dignissim turpis. Ut lacus leo, sagittis at ullamcorper eu, auctor a arcu. Sed non mi sed turpis rhoncus faucibus eu viverra.
      </p>
      <button type="button">Go Somewhere</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `!important` unless absolutely necessary such as overriding a 3rd party style. If it's all your own CSS there should be no reason to use `!important`, in my opinion.

Comment: @seantunwin It's my mistake! it will be fine without that !important. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add display: flex, flex-dicrection: column and justify-content: space-between.

Your new css .card class looks like:

```
.card{
    flex-basis: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

I hope this will work for you!